# templating T and T& under the same implementation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to have the same function with 2 interfaces because the implementation is the same for both and having the same function implemented in 2 overloaded signatures it's really not what I want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void foo(T&) {} // I have to write the same things here ...

template <typename T>
void foo(T) {} // ... and here

int main() {
  foo(std::vector<int>()); // call only for T

  std::vector<int> v;
  foo(v); // ambiguos call but I only need 1 implementation

  return (0);
}
```

Basically I would like to solve this situation and fuse the 2 templated functions into 1.

I have no clue because the main problem is keeping the same implementation and not just overload the signature or remove the use of the templates .

Comment: If there's no difference in implementation -- why provide an overload that takes the argument by value at all?

Comment: @arne take a look at the first call in the main

Comment: @user2485710 why not use rvalue-references?

Comment: @ForEveR probably because I need to take a nap, I totally forgot about Rvalues ... this can probably fix my problems, I will test this.

Comment: @user2485710 right. Wouldn't that work with const references though?

Comment: @ForEveR http://ideone.com/dFUcUB work perfectly, thanks :D

Comment: @arne what are saying exactly ?

Comment: @ForEveR for C++03 I can only use SFINAE ?

Comment: If you replace `T&` with `const T&`, the first call in main would still succeed, at the expense of not being able to change the parameter.

Comment: If the implementation does not try to modify the value that is passed, using `const &` should be equivalent in behavior to `&&` and gives the user the guarantuee that the value will not be changed

Comment: @arne ah, ok, I get now, It can be useful <del> yes, but in my case it's probably not, I need to write in that container.</del>

Comment: @user2485710 erm, but why can the implementation between the reference and non-reference variant be the same when you want to change the argument?

Comment: @arne I need to write on other arguments, that T&& is probably fine because I only need to read from that specific object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `rvalues` ?

**As interjay said : It is a _*universal reference*_, which could be either an _*rvalue reference*_ or an _*lvalue reference*_**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void foo(T&&) {}
//        ^^

int main() {
  foo(std::vector<int>());

  std::vector<int> v;
  foo(v);

  return (0);
}
```

`rvalues` will permit to have reference on temporary objects as well as normal objects.

> An **rvalue** (so-called, historically, because rvalues could appear on the right-hand side of an assignment expression) is an object, usually near the end of its lifetime, a temporary object or subobject thereof, or a value that is not associated with an object.

**EDIT :**

You can also use `const T&` but it will not allow you to modify the object :

```
template <typename T>
void foo( T&& v )
{
    v.push_back( 1 ); // good...
}

template <typename T>
void foo2( const T& v )
{
    v.push_back( 1 ); // ILLEGAL...
}
```

I would suggest you to use the last solution if you don't need to modify the objects at all.

Comment: the signature that can catch them all, http://ideone.com/dFUcUB yes it works, I totally forgot about this ... thanks to you too

Comment: The term "rvalue" is somewhat misleading here. This is actually a universal reference, which could be either an rvalue reference or an lvalue reference.

Comment: @interjay Yes you are right. It is more a universal reference than a `rvalue`.

Comment: @interjay the only question that I'm trying to answer now is : is more const-correct this or `const T&` ? I mean what kind of objects can pass with `T&&` but not with `const T&` in this case ?

Comment: The difference will be that with a `const T&` you cannot modify the object... Look at the example in my post. But if you don't need to modify the objects in your function, prefer the `const T&` solution.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud I think I will stick with `const T&`, it will also make my code much more portable to C++03 eventually, just in case I will need that kind of flexibility. Thanks.